# Identifying image format by data

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-processing

Are there libraries in PHP or JS which can identify image formats by analyzing data? It should support BMP, JPG, GIF, PNG, TIFF and EMF.

Comment: Have you tried use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) or [image_type_to_mime_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)?

Comment: Depends on what you are making but cross browser best way is a hidden img, replace the src dynamically and get the element width and height, although it doesn't answer your question, worth mentioning it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function with PHP `getimagesize` :-

```
function is_image($path)
{
$a = getimagesize($path);
$image_type = $a[2];
//Add you image format        
if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

or you can use `exif_imagetype`

```
//Add you image format
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
```